# How to fetch data as it is from MySql Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I am trying to fetch Data from MySQL Database using PHP script from Server. I am able to get Data from Database, but I am not getting the exact string present in Database. In the result obtained the spaces between words get trimmed and result does not match with String present in Database.

For Example:

The value inserted to Database is as shown Below:

```
SELENIUM INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:
What is Selenium?
Selenium is a set of tools that supports rapid development of test automation scripts for web based applications. Selenium testing tools provides a rich set of testing functions specifically designed to fulfill needs of testing of a web based application.
What are the main components of Selenium testing tools?
Selenium IDE, Selenium RC and Selenium Grid
```

The result obtained from the Database query shows the data as:

```
SELENIUM INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:What is Selenium?Selenium is a set of tools that supports rapid development of test automation scripts for web basedapplications. Selenium testing tools provides a rich set of testing functions specifically designed to fulfill needs of testing of a web based application.What are the main components of Selenium testing tools?Selenium IDE, Selenium RC and Selenium Grid
```

Can any one please let me know what changes should I make in my script to obtain data as it is shown in database from my query. I am using `mysql_real_escape_String` while inserting and I am using `stripslashes` while retrieving data from database.

Below is my PHP script:

Insert Script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "iFocusBlogs";


        $obtainedName = urldecode($_POST['enteredName']);
       $obtainedUserName = urldecode($_POST['enteredUserName']);
       $obtainedsubjectText = urldecode($_POST['subjectText']);
       $obtaineddetailsText   = urldecode($_POST['detailsText']);
       $status  = urldecode($_POST['status']);         

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$obtainedsubjectText = $conn->real_escape_string($obtainedsubjectText);
$obtaineddetailsText = $conn->real_escape_string($obtaineddetailsText);


$sql = "INSERT INTO AndroidTable (Name, UserName, Subject, Details, Status)
VALUES ('$obtainedName', '$obtainedUserName', '$obtainedsubjectText', '$obtaineddetailsText', '$status')";

mysqli_commit($conn);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Inserted Post sent to Moderator for Approval. Once approved from Moderator, Post will be displayed";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

fetch Script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "iFocusBlogs";



$obtainedUserName = 1;         

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql="SELECT Name, Subject FROM AndroidTable WHERE Status ='" .$obtainedUserName. "'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
foreach($row as $rows){
    for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++){
    echo  stripslashes($rows) . " ";
        $n=$i;

    }

}
    echo "<br/>";

    }


$conn->close();
?>
```

Please let me know what mistake am I doing in my script. All suggestions are welcome. If more information required please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Di your `name` column contain questions and `Subject` column contains there corresponding answers?

Comment: I think your script just returns what's in the database. In HTML the line breaks are then ignored, since you will have to either wrap the answer in <pre>..</pre> tags or replace line breaks by the <br> tag

Comment: @anantkumarsingh No, Name is the person name and subject is content the person posts

Comment: @AndréSchild Yes it displays but it ignores those sapces, I want the query to return data including spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), which will convert new line characters to `<br>`, so wherever you are echoing, you just need to call `nl2br` function, see example below:

```
echo  nl2br(stripslashes($rows)) . " ";
```

**EDIT:**

To get spaces instead of `<br>`, you can simply replace new line character `\n` with space, or anything you would like to replace with, see example below:

```
echo str_replace("\n", " ", stripslashes($rows))
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
echo stripslashes(str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n'), "<br>", $rows));
```

Comment: Ok. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Is there a function to display spaces instead of <br> I need to display this text in android application so It will be helpful if I get sapces instead of <br>

Comment: Updated answer if i give in script is it enough, I need to use both nl2br and the updated answer right?

Comment: I get <br>, but I wont get \n in the result so i need to replace \n with space?

Comment: `str_replace("\n", "<br>&nbsp;", stripslashes($rows))` this will replace new line char with br tag and a single space. is this what you need ?

Comment: No, since I am using real_escape_string while inserting it will add \n for new line and \' for apostrophe. So now while I am fetching I want to script to search for the \n and I want the text to be moved to next line when \n is encountered. I am able to remove \ from \' by using strip slashes

Comment: My main issue is when it encounters \n it is not moving to next line, what should be done to achieve that please help me.

Comment: Now as per your suggestions its giving me a space instead of pushing it to next line.

Comment: I see, try updated answer, that would probably work, actually that's not new line char anymore.

Comment: your updated answer is giving back what I was getting initially.. its not pushing the text to next line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82046/discussion-between-kamal-pal-and-keshav).